# counting and probability question - help needed

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, self-learning

I am stuck on how to start this exercise. Any help is welcome.

An instructor gives an exam with 14 questions. Students are allowed to choose any 10 to answer. Suppose the exam instructions specify that at most 1 of questions 1 and 2 may be included among the 10. How many different choices of 10 questions are there?

I have made a few attempts so far with no luck. Here is some of what I have tried. 
1. $\binom{14}8 = 3003$ This is incorrect 
2. $\binom{14}9 = 2002$ This is incorrect 
3. $\binom{10}8 = 45 $ This is incorrect

I have tried others with similar results, so any help is appreciated. I just don't know how to get this started.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide into cases:

(i) We use neither Q1 nor Q2. Then we must **choose** $10$ from the remaining $12$.

(ii) We use one of Q1 or Q2. We must choose $1$ from these $2$, and $9$ from the remaining $12$.

Add the answers to (i) and (ii).

**Another way:** Alternately, find the total number of choices, with no restriction. Then subtract the number of **bad** choices, where we picked both Q1 and Q2. There are $\binom{12}{8}$ bad choices.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help. I was able to figure this out using your second method by using $\binom{12}8$ and subtracting this from $\binom{14}{10}$. But, I was unable to figure it out using your first method, where you broke it up into choices.

Comment: For your first method, I tried: $\binom{12}{10} = 66$ and $\binom{12}9 = $220. Where you say, "choose 1 from these 2," do you mean I should write $\binom{2}1$? I don't think you do, but I thought I should clarify this. If I add 66 and 220 I will not get the correct answer so I am missing something here.

Comment: Yes, my answer was meant to imply that you need to multiply $\binom{12}{9}$ by $2$. That gives answer $506$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying this for me.